# Use Paramiko's stdout as stdin with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, paramiko

How can I execute a command on a remote server in Python and pipe the stdout to a local command? To do `ssh host 'echo test' | cat` in Python, I have tried

```
import paramiko
import subprocess

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('host', username='user')
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command('echo test')
proc = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdin=ssh_stdout)
outs, errs = proc.communicate()
print(outs)
```

but I get the exception `'ChannelFile' object has no attribute 'fileno'`. It seems that Paramiko's `ssh_stdout` can't be used as stdin with subprocess.Popen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `subprocess` cannot redirect output on a "fake" file. It needs `fileno` which is defined only with "real" files (`io.BytesIO()` doesn't have it either).

I would do it manually like the following code demonstrates:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(ssh_stdout.read())
proc.stdin.close()
```

so you're telling `Popen` that the input is a *pipe*, and then you write ssh output data in the pipe (and close it so `cat` knows when it must end)

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, the `ChannelFile` object does not directly wrap an actual file descriptor (because of the decryption and demuxing and so on that occurs within SSH), so it can't directly be used as a file descriptor for `Popen`.

Something like

```
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command('echo test')
proc = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
while proc.poll() is not None:  # (fixed)
   buf = ssh_stdout.read(4096)
   if not buf:
       break
   proc.stdin.write(buf)
```

might work; i.e. you read the SSH stdout stream manually, up to 4096 bytes at a time, and write them to the subprocess's stdin pipe.
I'm not sure how the code above will behave when the remote command exits, though, so YMMV.

Comment: `while not proc.poll():` is not really necessary, and it's _wrong_. On successful completion, it returns 0. You have to do `while proc.poll() is not None:` to actively wait for program exit.